# CSS trouble on List Menu (UL / LI) with user defined icons

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have a LI / UL menu, where the user stores the items himself.

The problems:

1. there is a small value (red/bubble) left/top of the ICON (image) which is not correctly located on subitems
2. The text should be in the middle of the height of the image, but it is always on the ground line...

Anyone with a hint or code example how to solve this?

```css
ul.navigation {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px
}
.navigation .item.first {
  padding: 0px
}
.navigation li {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 25px;
}
.navigation .item img {
  height: 25px;
}
.navigation .item span {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
.navigation .item i {
  background-color: #fa3e3e;
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: white;
  padding: 1px 3px;
  font-size: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  /* Position the badge within the relatively positioned button */
  z-index: 5;
  left: 40px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navigation">
  <li class="item first">
    <i>24</i>
    <img src="assets/icons/dashboard.png" />
    <span>Caption of Navigation Item</span>
    <ul class="navigation">
      <li class="item">
        <i>24</i>
        <img src="assets/icons/dashboard.png" />
        <span>Caption of Navigation Item</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: A few things: 1. It would be useful to see / have the `dashboard.png` image, so we could know how large it is, how alignment should happen, etc.  2. You say the red bubble is not correctly located.  Where *should* it be?  Here's a fiddle I've set up that we can test / play with: https://jsfiddle.net/cale_b/56q7x6aw/

Comment: first → I made an update of the fiddle   https://jsfiddle.net/56q7x6aw/7/

Comment: then → I figured out that giving the item a position: relative, fixes the position of the small bubble.. I just have to update the .nav .item i from left: position to margin-left : .....

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working template based on your requirements:

```css
ul.navigation {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px
}
.navigation .item.first {
  padding: 0px
}
.navigation li {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 25px;
}
.navigation .item img {
  height: 40px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.navigation .item span {
  line-height: 40px;
}
.navigation .item i {
  background-color: #fa3e3e;
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: white;
  padding: 1px 3px;
  font-size: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navigation">
  <li class="item first">
    <i>24</i>
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" width="40" height="40" alt="">
    <span>Caption of Navigation Item</span>
    <ul class="navigation">
      <li class="item">
        <i>24</i>
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" width="40" height="40" alt="">
        <span>Caption of Navigation Item</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

### [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1ydu6pcj/1/)

Comment: perfect, thats what I was looking for... Will analyse it... Thank you very much, took me 3 hours to find no solution

Comment: Have to learn this stuff (CSS) now. Also SASS ... And it feels like hell heavy stuff for me...